# Float and width are not doing what they should be doing in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

There are two problems with my code: **(1)** the float parameter in CSS is affecting items that should be completely irrelevant and **(2)** either width or float or maybe both are not working as expected with another element (carry on reading and it will be simpler).

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <a class="nav-title-link" href="/">
        <div class="nav-logo-section">
            <div id="titleText" class="title-text">
                <h2>My Title</h2>
            </div>
            <img class="nav-logo" src="MY SOURCE">
        </div>
    </a>
    <div id="navRight" class="nav-right">
        <!-- Some content here that is irrelevant to the problem -->
    </div
</nav>
<div id="irrelevant">
    <div class="main-content">
        <h1 class="main-title">Catchphrase</h1>
        <p class="main-paragraph">Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box" class="box">
       <!-- Some content in the box -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-logo-section {
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 30px;
    float: left;
}
.nav-logo {
    height: 50px;
}
.title-text {
    color: #252f3f;
    line-height: 0.5;
    float: left;
}

.main-content {
    padding: 50px 75px 0 75px;
    width: calc(50% - 150px);
    float: left;
}

.box {
    float: right;
    margin: 75px 100px 0 0;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background: white;
}
```

**1st Problem**

For some reason, the `nav-logo-section` seems to be affecting the position of the `main-content` as seen in the image below (the `main-content` should be almost flush with the left side of the screen):

[image: This is the result of the code (1st problem)]

**2nd Problem**

The second problem is when I remove `float: left` on the `main-content` element to avoid the 1st problem the `box` element doesn't go side by side with the `main-content` element as seen in the image below:

[image: This is the result of the code (2nd problem)]

A possible problem that I found is that `width` seems to be acting as a `margin` in the `main-content` element for some reason as seen when inspecting the webpage:

[image: This is what the main-content div looks like]

I am really stuck here and as you can see, everything is a bit of a mess. If you have any possible solutions please tell me. Thank you

Comment: **Never** use `float` for layout purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using flexbox for the nav insteado of float? Basically you have 2 sections inside the nav, one pulled to the left and one pulled to the right, you can use

```
.nav{
display: flex,
width: 100%
justify-content: space-between
}
```

And perhaps flexbox can help you to the second problem as well

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed problem 1 and problem 2!